# Deployment of lightning community shows as classic in destination org

Tags: community, lightning-community

If I deploy the lightning community, in destination org I see the community as classic.

No matter what I do or how many times I redeploy, the outcome is same. I even tried comparing the metadata locally, no differences.

The value of setting [`Enable ExperienceBundle Metadata API`](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/02/experiencebundle-salesforce-dx-a-developers-dream-for-coding-lighting-communities.html) doesn't make any difference.

Even the login page type shows as default page which is classic:

[image]

---

Background:

Had to convert the classic to lightning communities and the older community was build with basic OOTB features.

- I was easily able to create a new lightning (based on the old classic community) on our DEV environment.
- Used `partner central` template.
- Next was easy step to do the deployment.

---

Now I had heard/read issues with lightning community deployment but this time I was lucky to experience this issue myself.

We have our CI/CD process with copado (copado here is not very relevant as I have same problem with SFDX/ANT migration tool and even changeset).

Following components I tried to deploy with changeset (and other tools):

[image]

Reference articles:

1. [Deploy Lightning Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000323350&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)
2. [Deploy a Community from Sandbox to Production](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_migrate_overview.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wasting roughly a week and some rest found a workaround/solution today.

Trick to get this right in such circumstance is:

1. Deactivate the community in destination org.
2. Redeploy the community from source environment.
3. After deployment, publish the lightning community.
4. Profit!

Now after deployment with these steps I was able to get the correct lightning version community in my destination orgs. And the login page also correct after deployment.

[image]

---

Note: Posting the solution here for anyone else having similar problem in future. Please feel free to mark this as duplicate if there is similar question that I could not find.

Comment: out of curiosity, did you try using the ExperienceBundle metadata type in a change set vs. using the site.com and did you run into the same issue?

Comment: Hi @Kris, I just checked my previous commits, I did try after enabling the `Enable ExperienceBundle Metadata API` in source org, then did a pull to get changes and tried to deploy via copado and force.com migration tool. No luck, didn't try that specific scenario with a changeset. It had bunch of files under the folder `experiences/Partner_Lightning1/*/*.json` (about 111 JSON files).